# how can i make my timer to reload to page when the countdown ends?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

hello i am trying to make a countdown which refreshes the page when the countdown finished 
however the timer is not refreshing page when countdown ends it start more counting in clock wise 
for example the timer has to reload the page after 3 , 2 ,1 , but it goes like 3, 2, 1 , 1, 2 ,3 and so on below is my code

```
    <?php if (isset($alert)) { ?>
<script type='text/javascript'>$('#alert').modal('show');</script>
<?php  } ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="template/js/site.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#DateCountdown").TimeCircles();
    $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles({ time: { Days: { show: false }, Hours: { show: false } }});
    $("#PageOpenTimer").TimeCircles();

    var updateTime = function(){
        var date = $("#date").val();
        var time = $("#time").val();
        var datetime = date + ' ' + time + ':00';
        $("#DateCountdown").data('date', datetime).TimeCircles().start();
    }
    $("#date").change(updateTime).keyup(updateTime);
    $("#time").change(updateTime).keyup(updateTime); 
    $(".startTimer").click(function() {
        $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().start();
    });
    $(".stopTimer").click(function() {
        $("#CountDownTimer").TimeCircles().stop();
    }); 
    $(".fadeIn").click(function() {
        $("#PageOpenTimer").fadeIn();
    });
    $(".fadeOut").click(function() {
        $("#PageOpenTimer").fadeOut();
    });   
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
}, 1500)
```

Swap out the 1500 for the time in ms that you want to pass before reloading the page.

Comment: not possible because the time to refresh is on another file

Answer (score 0):

Can't see timeout/interval routines in your code, so I'll show my example to do what you want:

```js
// your timeout in seconds
var timeSec = 10;       
// fix countdown start time in seconds
var timeStart = parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);  

// function to check if time is up
function TimeCheck() {
    // get time left in seconds
    var timeLeft = timeSec - (parseInt((new Date()).getTime() / 1000) - timeStart);
    // checking if time is up
    if(timeLeft > 0) {
        // if time is not up yet
        
        // ... do whatever you want to display / refresh time left to reload page ...
        
        // set "check timeout" for next check
        setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000); 
    }
    else {
        // reload page and don't set "check timeout" again
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

// initial timeout start
cTimeout = setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000);
```

Using `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()` prevents multiple instances of callback functions to stuff in execution queue.

Comment: my time to refresh is on another file so this will not work

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by "on another file" ? Are you trying to refresh another browser tab / frame after the timeout? Or you have your timeout value in another browser tab / frame ?

Comment: no the time to refresh is in my config file with value $faucet['time'] = 60;  // time to wait  in second. so the site will refresh after 60 seconds

Comment: `var timeSec = <?=$faucet['time']?>;` ?

Comment: yes var timeSec= <?=$faucet['time']?> and the code you gave me removes my timer interface too :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean this code to solve the problem?

```
$("#CountDownTimer")
    .TimeCircles({count_past_zero: false})   // prevent countdown below zero
    .addListener(countdownComplete);         // add "countdown complete listener"

function countdownComplete(unit, value, total){
    if(total <= 0){
        // ... make your page refresh ...
    }
}
```